# How can I use a LINQ statement to filter out items that matches one of the words from another List?

Tags: c#, list, linq, filter, iterator

I'm trying to get a list of properties of my object except a few ones(who matches a few strings and the ones which are null), the default list looks like follows:

[image]

I already filter out the properties which are null, now I want to use LINQ to filter out "TypeId" ,"SubTypeId", "TypeDescription" and "SubTypeDescription", therefore i created a list:

```
List<string> standardProperties = new List<string> { "TypeId", "TypeDescription", "SubTypeId", "SubTypeDescription" };
```

My Linq query looks like this atm:

```
Report reportProperties = item.First();

List<string> standardProperties = new List<string> { "TypeId", "TypeDescription", "SubTypeId", "SubTypeDescription" };


@foreach (var prop in typeof(Report).GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetValue(reportProperties) != null))
{
    <GridColumn Field="@prop.Name" AllowEditing="@prop.CanWrite"></GridColumn>
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `x => x.GetValue(reportProperties) != null && !standardProperties.Contains(x.Name)`

Comment: I would suggest using a `HashSet` instead of `List` when your primary purpose is `Contains` testing - it will generally be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a class `Report`. This class has zero or more properties, and you want all `PropertyInfos` of the `Report` class, except the `PropertyInfos` of properties `Report.TypeId, Report.TypeDescription, etc`.

Of course you can check on the names of the properties using strings. The problem of this is that you will only detect errors at runtime. It would be better to compare on propertyInfos:

```
var reportType = typeof(Report);
var propertiesToIgnore = new PropertyInfo[]
{
    reportType.GetProperty(nameof(Report.TypeId)),
    reportType.GetProperty(nameof(Report.TypeDescription)),
    reportType.GetProperty(nameof(Report.SubTypeId)),
    ...
}

var propertiesToProcess = reportType.GetProperties()
    .Except(propertiesToIgnore);

foreach (var property in propertiesToProcess)
{
    // process the property
    ...
}
```

Advantage: if someone changes the name of one of the properties, the problem will be detected at compile time, instead of at runtime.